# Visit statistics at or near zero

Tags: bug, area-51, moderator-tools, site-visits

The home page of [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) currently shows "6 visitors/day".
Alarmed by this number (instead of, say, 600 visitors per day), I visited [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language), where the number was 3.
I then checked the moderator tools and the statistics claim that there have been zero or one visits on most days, apart from the period April 6–11.
(I will not reproduce moderator-only data here.)
It looks as if visits are not only no longer recorded, but also most of visit history is erased.

I don't have mod tools on other site, but for another data point the [Language Learnind Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) says that there were zero visits per day.
The issue is thus not limited to Latin, but I don't know how broad it is.

What's up with the visit counts?
Is this a temporary glitch that should resolve itself?